# groovy sql framework

Tags: java, groovy

Hi I want to design a class using [Groovy Sql](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GROOVY/Tutorial+6+-+Groovy+SQL) which I will be able to use in any of my future db related projects. At present I came up with the below class, which has separate functions for individual queries, I want to learn how can I make it generic! So that I just need to pass `1 query` and some `bind parameters (if not pass null)` Please help me get a solution

My code

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.List;
import groovy.sql.Sql

public class ProductInfo {

  ReadProperty prop

  def sql
  public ProductInfo()
  {
    prop=ReadProperty.getInstance("db")
    sql = Sql.newInstance("jdbc:oracle:thin:@"+prop.getProperty("hostname")+":"+prop.getProperty("port")+":"+prop.getProperty("service"), "asimonc", "asimon","oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver")
  }

  public List executeSelection(String query)
  {
    List result=new ArrayList()
    sql.eachRow(query)
    { 
      String[] rows=new String[5]
      rows[0]=(String)it.id
      rows[1]=(String)it.name
      rows[2]=(String)it.description
      rows[3]=(String)it.active
      rows[4]=(String)it.release_date

      result.add(rows)
    }
    return result
  }

  public executeInsert(String query,Object[] paramValues)
  {
    sql.execute(query,[paramValues[0], paramValues[1],paramValues[2], paramValues[3], paramValues[4]])
  }

  public executeUpdation(String query,Object[] paramValues)
  {
    sql.executeUpdate(query,[paramValues[1], paramValues[2],paramValues[4],paramValues[5], paramValues[0]])
  }

  public int executeSelectMax(String query)
  {
    int max     
    sql.eachRow(query) 
    {
      max=it.max
    }
    if(max==null)
      return 0
    else
      return max
  }
}
```

My oracle table

```
CREATE TABLE PRODUCTINFO
(     "ID" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
      "NAME" NVARCHAR2(200), 
      "DESCRIPTION" NVARCHAR2(200), 
      "ACTIVE" NVARCHAR2(2), 
      "RELEASE_DATE" DATE, 
       PRIMARY KEY ("ID")
)
```

for finding out max id (**selection**)

```
ProductInfo pinfo= new ProductInfo();
int max=pinfo.executeSelectMax("select max(id) as max from productinfo");
```

for **updation**

```
Object[] paramValues={iid,name,desc,"A",date,active};
pinfo.executeUpdation("update productinfo set name=?, description=?, release_date=?, active=? where id=?",paramValues);
```

for **insertion**

```
Object[] paramValues={max+1,name,desc,"A",date};
pinfo.executeInsert("insert into productinfo(ID,NAME,DESCRIPTION,ACTIVE,RELEASE_DATE) values (?,?,?,?,?)",paramValues);
```

for yet another **selection**

```
List result=pinfo.executeSelection("select ID,NAME,DESCRIPTION,ACTIVE,RELEASE_DATE from productinfo where ACTIVE='A'");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
import groovy.sql.Sql

public class ProductInfo {

  ReadProperty prop

  def sql
  public ProductInfo() {
    prop=ReadProperty.getInstance("db")
    sql = Sql.newInstance( "jdbc:oracle:thin:@"+prop.getProperty("hostname")+":"+prop.getProperty("port")+":"+prop.getProperty("service"), "asimonc", "asimon","oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver")
  }

  public List executeSelection(String query) {
    List result = []
    sql.eachRow(query) { 
      result << [ it.id, it.name, it.description, it.active, it.release_date ]
    }
    result
  }

  public void executeInsert( GString query ) {
    sql.execute( query )
  }

  public void executeUpdation( GString query ) {
    sql.executeUpdate( query )
  }

  public int executeSelectMax( String query ) {
    sql.firstRow(query)?.max ?: 0
  }
}
```

Then, your update and insert examples become:

update:

```
pinfo.executeUpdation( "update productinfo set name=$name, description=$desc, release_date=$date, active=${'A'} where id=$iid" )
```

insert:

```
pinfo.executeInsert( "insert into productinfo(ID,NAME,DESCRIPTION,ACTIVE,RELEASE_DATE) values (${max+1}, $name, $desc, ${'A'}, $date )" )
```

As you can see... a lot of your code is simply wrapping things [that](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/sql/Sql.html#executeInsert%28groovy.lang.GString%29) [already](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/sql/Sql.html#executeUpdate%28groovy.lang.GString%29) [exist](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/sql/Sql.html#firstRow%28java.lang.String%29) in the `groovy.sql.Sql` class

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. what about if I am using a jsp page to give out these queries? Will it still work? Also  in your `executeSelection` method `it.id`, `it.name` ... are hardcoded.. what If I am trying to execute some other select query?

Comment: No, as a JSP will have no knowledge of a GString.  Maybe this massive snippet of information should have been in the question?  And I would warn you that if there's SQL in the JSP directly, you probably want to have a rethink...  Database calls in the presentation layer are usually a Very Bad Thing :-/

Comment: So how can I provide the bind parameters and not hardcoded? Also can you suggest, how should I use SQL in my webapp apart from using it directly from the jsp?

Comment: Write some sort of controller class with methods that match the things you want to do (add user, update fields, etc) then call these methods from the JSP. Otherwise, you're going to have a maintenance nightmare when you have bits of SQL spread across all the JSPs in your codebase...  For small things it's fine, but if it grows, you're going to be in a lot of pain...

Comment: K 1 problem solved :) Now `executeSelection` is always executing query from a single Oracle table, what about if I want to execute a query which takes data from some another oracle table? Do I always need to write different functions for each `select query` as `it.id, it.name ...` is already specified in the function

Comment: Surely you know what functions you want to execute, so writing a self documenting function for each isn't too bad?

Comment: Yes that's a solution which can be made use of, but as in normal JDBC where you can give bind parameters, and depending on the length of the bind parameters in some map you can substitute all the necessary values, I am thinking something similar to that. Is this possible in Groovy Sql?